# Skip over commits in Git for a branch (using SourceTree)

Tags: git, git-branch, sourcetree

I have a few commits in my repo, but for the moment, I want to build without the first 2 changes. How can I make a branch to go from where I was before these commits (`Old` code), jump over 2 of them (`A and B`), and use the Third (`C`)?

Here is (basically) what I have now, all in one master branch:

```
Old---A---B---C (Master)
```

Here is something along the lines of what I'd like:

```
Old---A---B---C (Master)  
   \----------C (New_Branch)
```

Then I would intend to temporarily build from New_Branch, then get rid of it when finished. Is there a way to skip over/temporarily drop commits like this? I've tried branching but I always seen to pick up every commit along the way, so that my branches end up identical.

Answer (score 1):

With plain git you would use

```
git branch New_Branch Old
git checkout New_Branch
git cherry-pick C
```

I don't know how to do this with SourceTree.

Comment: I think CherryPicking with SourceTree just grabs everything up to what you're cherry picking (at least from what I could tell)... But I can also try this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could right click the commit on C and create a new branch. This new branch will hold commits A, B and C. You can then right click A and do 'reverse commit', repeat this with commit B. 
However if commit C changes code/files from commit A and B then you could get into a bit of a mess.